# InvalidArgumentException: A 'contents' key is required with fake UploadedFile

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Hello I'm trying to test HTTP attach with a faker uploaded file however I keep geeting `InvalidArgumentException: A 'contents' key is required`.

Did I miss anything?

When I try to dump the fake uploaded file I got the ff.

```
Illuminate\Http\Testing\File^ {#1808
  +name: "test.docx"
  +tempFile: stream resource {@706
    timed_out: false
    blocked: true
    eof: false
    wrapper_type: "plainfile"
    stream_type: "STDIO"
    mode: "r+b"
    unread_bytes: 0
    seekable: true
    uri: "/private/var/folders/88/qdbqbd6j657_3cr43nw29ywh0000gp/T/phpZ7vpwW"
    options: []
  }
  +sizeToReport: 102400
  +mimeTypeToReport: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
  name: "test.docx"
  tempFile: stream resource @706
  sizeToReport: 102400
  mimeTypeToReport: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
  -test: true
  -originalName: "test.docx"
  -mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/private/var/folders/88/qdbqbd6j657_3cr43nw29ywh0000gp/T"
  filename: "phpZ7vpwW"
  basename: "phpZ7vpwW"
  pathname: "/private/var/folders/88/qdbqbd6j657_3cr43nw29ywh0000gp/T/phpZ7vpwW"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/private/var/folders/88/qdbqbd6j657_3cr43nw29ywh0000gp/T/phpZ7vpwW"
  aTime: 2021-10-05 12:47:58
  mTime: 2021-10-05 12:47:58
  cTime: 2021-10-05 12:47:58
  inode: 94773635
  size: 102400
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 502
  group: 20
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

however when I try to dump `$file->get()` I got an empty string

FileUploader class

```
class FileUploader implements IFileScanner {
  public function upload(UploadedFile $file) {
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
      'X-Request-ID' => Str::random(6),
    ])
    ->attach('file', $file->get(), $file->getFilename())
    ->post('http://example.com/upload');

    if ($response->successful()) {
      return $response->object();
    }

    if ($response->clientError() || $response->serverError()) {
      $response->throw();
    }
  }
}
```

FileUploaderTest class

```
public function testShouldReturnOkWhenFileIsUninfected() {
    Http::fake([
      'http://example.com/upload' => Http::response([
        'infected'=> false,
        'result' => '',
        'error' => '',
        'executionTimeMS' => '',
      ]),
    ], 200);

    $uploadedFile = UploadedFile::fake()->create(
      'test.docx',
      1000,
      'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
    );
    
    $fileScanner = new FileUploader();
    $response = $fileScanner->scan($uploadedFile);

    $this->assertEquals($response, [
      'infected'=> false,
      'result' => '',
      'error' => '',
      'executionTimeMS' => '',
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of digging, I was finally able to solve it. just in case someone encounter this kind of error. I found out that there is `createWithContent`.

`$uploadedFile = UploadedFile::fake()->createWithContent('test.docx', 'test only')`